# want to get Numlock on at startup in kubuntu

Tags: keyboard, kde

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Numlock turned on on boot-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17207/numlock-turned-on-on-boot-up)

i wanted to get the keyboard Numlock on when starting the computer. To accomplish this i went to system settings -> input devices -> keyboard and in the section "Numlock on when kde starts" checked "Turn on".

But that is not lighting up the NumLocK at startup.

what is the right place to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2):

Edit /etc/kde4/kdm/Xsetup (if you are still running kde3 you'll need to edit /etc/kde3/kdm/Xsetup instead) and add the following code to it:

if [ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ]; then
  /usr/bin/numlockx on
fi

That code should work if you install numlockx (sudo apt-get install numlockx)